# How to avoid global variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, global

How can I avoid using global variables in JavaScript?

```
  //load more
  var size_li = $("#myList li").size();
  var x = 3;
  $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
  $('.loadmore').on('click', function() {
      x = (x + 2 <= size_li) ? x + 2 : size_li;
      $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
  });
```

Comment: This is not what you asked so I won't include it in my answer, but the line `x = (x + 2 <= size_li) ? x + 2 : size_li;` can be simplified to `x = Math.min(x + 2, size_li);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good technique for this is a self-executing closure:

```
// bob is a global variable, which you want to avoid
var bob = 1;

// By wrapping this function declaration in parentheses, then
// appending (), it gets invoked immediately. But everything
// inside it is scoped to the anonymous function!
(function () {
    // sue can only be seen inside this function
    var sue = 1;

    // But if you want to, you can still create global variables.
    // This creates a global variable called joe:
    window.joe = 1;
})();
```

Applying this technique to your code, you could write this to have no global variables:

```
(function() {
    var size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    var x = 3;

    $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
    $('.loadmore').on('click', function() {
        x = (x + 2 <= size_li) ? x + 2 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I know is in es6, which has 'let' could define a variable inside block

eg:

```
var b = 5
{
let a = 10
}
a//undefine
b// is 5
```